# Cycling and launching apps through holding down power button: extra support for blind users

Tags: applications, google, buttons, operating-system, accessibility

I want to use Android as a person that cannot read (for example, as a blind user), in a supermarket to read out what's in front in me via voice, using headphones, by pointing my Android phone with Google Lookout to the bar code or handwriting below each item I consider for purchase (and, the supermarkets I have been to, have barcodes or descriptive handwriting next to the items that can be purchased).

In order for this to work well, I would like to quickly open up Google Lookup by pressing holding down the power button and skipping beyond the power off/reboot screen and having an app suggested (in this case, Google Lookup), and have it fire up upon releasing the power button.

This would be very comfortable, and intuitive, for a blind user.

This is just a use case. Let me describe the generic functionality I am looking for.

I would like to configure a list of power off/reboot screen, app 1 screen (minimized, sort of like when you view your apps to choose from with the apps software button, but with just one app), that opens up when the power button is released), app 2, ..., app n.

While the user holds down the power button, the phone cycles through this list, displaying the app in a smaller rectangle, not occupying the whole screen, and opens it up when the power button is released. The user may then return to normal phone functioning and interact with the app normally. The app name is displayed above or below the app in smaller size when the user keeps the power button pressed.

This list can be configured in accessibility settings.

When TalkBack is enabled, and the power button is pressed, the name of the power off/reboot screen or app to be fired out on release is spoken out loud.

I feel that this would be a major step on making the phone more user friendly, to blind users, especially to younger blind users, that were getting accustomed, to using a device, and found a power button to interact with, which, once configured in Google accessibility settings, also via Google Assistant, could do all of this.

This would be nice.

Where can I find this behavior on Android?

When will this behavior be implemented?

I am using an Android 12 reale t8 5G phone.

Thank you for your feedback.

Thank you for your support.

Thanks.

Comment: The cycling action may be a bit much with out custom development, but an app called Tasker could be used to tie a long press to a volume button to launch an app like the camera, although it doesn't seem you can use the power button. Let me know  if you'd be interested in this!